# Xcode freezes after adding 2500 svg image to the asset

Tags: xcode, assets

Xcode freezes after adding 2500 svg images to the asset (MacBook M1 Pro)

After adding images, I was able to compile the project and install it on the phone where it works and everything is ok, but Xcode freezes even at startup and starts indexing which takes a very long time.

How do I manage a large number of images?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/EnablingODR.html